# Let images work properly online and offline (MAMP)

Tags: media, wysiwyg, files

I just started using MAMP to work offline on my drupal-projects.

Because MAMP and working offline is new to me I started today with a test-website.

I installed MAMP, no problems.

I installed a new drupal 7.30 offline in MAMP, no problems.
I imported the CKEDITOR and IMCE for uploading images, no problems.

I created two test-pages and imported in each page a image using CKEDITOR & IMCE, no problems.

After that i tried to upload my offline website online: backup DB, create a new DB online, imported the offline DB, FTP my files online, change the settings-file for connecting instructions DB.

After all those steps my website was showing up online and i could login. Everything seems to work fine.

But then when i clicked one of the testpages, i saw that my images where not showing up...

When i checked the sourcecode i saw something like this:

When i removed /sweetmorning, and saved that code, the image was showing up again.

What is the best practice to still work with CKEDITOR IMCE and let the images showup offline and also after i put the website online.

Any tips, links, info are welcome :-)

Thanks in advance,
Kristof

Answer (score 1):

Part of your code did not go through; however I believe it's pretty clear that the issue is in image paths.

Check out [Pathologic](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathologic) module, as it deals with exactly such issues:

> Pathologic is an input filter which can correct paths in links and images in your Drupal content in situations which would otherwise cause them to “break;” for example, if the URL of the site changes, or the content was moved to a different server. Pathologic can also solve the problem of missing images and broken links in your site’s RSS feeds. See more example use cases on the documentation page.

Comment: I tried this module "Pathologic" but this didn't fix my problem. I will try to look further with this module. But not even sure if the solution is in there... the part in the url ( sweetmorning/... ) refers to the map in htdocs wher my project is in offline. that part should disapear when transferrring my website online...

Comment: Exactly that is the problem Pathologic solves. Maybe you did not configure it properly - give it another try and read the instructions [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/257026).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I tried a little bit more with Pathologic. I did read the instructions and saw a instruction movie... But the only thing that happend was that http:localhost8888 was changed by my domainname online. I did not reach to the point where i could let the part sweetmorning/ dissapear. I geuss its also possible with Pathologic. But i did find a good solution without to have to install an extra module... I made a virtual host for my mamp, so the start of the url didn't used the name of the map in HTDOCS. Did fixed my problem and the pictures do show up online:-)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can information how i fixed the problem:

http://sawmac.com/mamp/virtual/

This solution ensures that the name of the folder (project name - htdocs) in htdocs no longer used in the URL to the location of the photo. This creates NO problems when I place the website online.

With this i could move my offline project online and al the pictures showed up.

Probably a solution is also possible with Pathologic (and this looks like a good module, that can fix a lot of problems). So thank you again TOPSITEMAKERS.